# How to extrude all faces at the same time after select linked faces

Tags: faces, extrude

When I select faces by hand, I can extrude it with no problems. If I select faces with "L" (linked faces) then, the extrusion are separated from original faces.

The video shows first the result with the manual selection and then with the automatic selection with "L" (linked faces). Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

https://youtu.be/SyS5gb2gDmg

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: what version r u using?

Comment: Sorry, I've evolved the file. When I tried to rebuild it from scratch to share it, everything works fine. Can I discard this question?